# How to create external Javascript (.js File)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Iam new in javascript, I have a script that can work when I put in the footer before the `</ body>` in Wordpress, then I will convert to external javascript (.js file) but when I run it can not work. How to solve this problem?

This is script in footer and work,

```
function showMe() {
    var x = document.getElementById("codeArea").value;
    if (x.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtResponse").innerHTML = "empty";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtResponse").innerHTML  = this.responseText;              

                return;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "show.php?q="+x, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
```

And this is what I try to change to external javascript, example : showMe.js

```
function showMe() {
    'use strict';
    var x = document.getElementById("codeArea").value;
    if (x.length === 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtResponse").innerHTML = "empty";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtResponse").innerHTML  = this.responseText;              

                return;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "show.php?q="+x, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
```

Please give Me solution, thanks

Comment: Please show your html page

Comment: do you call the function that is inside the file **after** the file has been included?

Comment: use wp_enqueue_script to add the js file in the footer, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you put the snippet in your post. Any way just try including the js file just above the closing body tag i.e. `</body>` tag in the HTML file.

```
<html>
...
<body>
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="showMe.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file add an script Tag just before you close body:

```
<body>
--Content--
    <script src="dir/showMe.js"></script>
</body>
```

And next time pls add your HTML file , it is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
'use strict'
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you converting your js code into a file then follow steps:-

1.put the file into your theme js directory 

2. the call into footer file like this one

  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/showMe.js"></script>

before closing tag of </body>

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

If wordpress you can follow this 
[enter link description here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

else